# Тестинг API на PhpUnit. Помогите решить задачу

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Как проверить, если в массиве отсутствует какой-нибудь key, то дать ошибку?
При использовании `assertArrayHasKey`, проверяется есть ли такой `key` или нет, но не сообщает об отсутствии. 
Как можно это проверить?

Comment: Обязательно отмечу верный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати, вы можете разместить найденное решение в виде ответа, а не комментария и через 48 часов отметить его верным.

Comment: Спасибо за совет :)

Answer (score 2):

Пыхи под рукой нет, по документации

```
$this->assertThat(
    $data,
    $this->logicalNot(
        $this->arrayHasKey($key)
    )
);
```

Или сразу

```
$this->assertFalse(isset($data[$key]));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я решила проблему следующим образом: $count_key_of_array = count($jsonToArray);
$this->assertEquals(46, count($jsonToArray));